# Checkout progress not working

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm using custom magento theme, and changed a few things on it. I also wrote this problem to where I bought it.

I've been researched everything about that but nothing helped me.

When I use custom template's /layout/checkout.xml file It’s not progress to “payment information” tab, and also right sidebar checkout progress not working

If I change checkout.xml file from base theme’s checkout.xml file payment information can work very well but checkout progress still not working.

I'm trying to fix checkout progress problem.

Do you know any solution, anynone has same problem or just me?

Comment: Anything in Magneto logs (assuming you have them enabled) or/and JavaScript console?

Comment: Also it's not a good practice to rewrite `checkout.xml` in a custom theme. But how makes good themes these days :(

Comment: @Tim I enabled magento logs, but browser console is pretty clean even in all checkout step.

Comment: You can also try to check `XHR` responses at the `Network` tab of your browser. The request to failed checkout step should leave its trace there.

Comment: @Tim Actually, I revert to base theme's checkout.xml code. Now all step work very well but not checkout progress. Can I see progress's response on network tab?

Comment: Yes, of cause..

Comment: @Tim I can see progress data on network tab but in "checkout progress" div nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this on my site. Go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml or to your custom theme's payment.phtml to edit some code.

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

this fieldset needs an ID to progress

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

This should fix it for you. if not, be sure to clear all your cache.

Comment: glad you got this sorted, you can mark this answer as accepted if you think it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

after upgrade magento this issue will occurs because your current 
theme is older magento files so pleas rename your checkout.xml to 
checkout.xml-- and rename template checkout folder to checkout-- so that 
will load from base/default and this will solve your problem.